# Hive output query for selecting particular value based on groupby clause

Tags: hive

I have a table with data like:

```
cust_id, acct_no, ind
123111,  1233,     Y
123111,  2311,     N
222111,  1112,     N
222111,  2111,     N
```

I have to get output as `cust_id, 1` (a binary indicator if any of the acct under that customer is Y)

so from the above table I have to get below output.

```
123111    1
222111    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is something like:

```
select cust_id, max(case when ind = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as flag from customers group by cust_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Mark and it worked but i think you forgot to include group by cust_id.

Comment: yes you're right. Sorry, I update the answer..